# Spunk Java SDK job.isDone() never gets true

Tags: sdk, splunk

I am using Java splunk SDK below is my code

```
String mySearch = "search * | head 5";
Job job = service.getJobs().create(mySearch);

while (!job.isDone()) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
}

InputStream results = job.getResults();
```

The while loop never gets completed, did anyone faced this issue.

Comment: did the authentication worked ?

Comment: Yes the authentication worked, I Used **Service.connect()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the job state is not refreshed, that is why the `job.isDone()` always return `false`

Try to refresh after the Thread sleep code, like this

```
while (!job.isDone()) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    job.refresh();
}
```

The **`job.refresh()`** method should update the status of the job, then you should get `true`